# change my json string in a loop

Tags: json, perl

Right now I have my json that is created from a select from mysql and looks like this:

```
$sth->execute()
  or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ){
    push @output, $row;
    # print $row->{image};
    $photo = $row->{image};
    my $file = "$photo";
    my $document = do {
        local $/ = undef;
        open my $fh, "<", $file
          or die "could not open $file: $!";
        <$fh>;
    };

    my $encoded= MIME::Base64::encode_base64($document);
}
```

With the JSON looking like this:

```
{"myData":[{"favorited":null,"date":"2013-07-31","preferredMeetingLocation":"meet here","description":"Clothes desc","image":"/var/www/pictures/photo-7h1sIsXQ.jpg","id":"31","title":"clothing ","price":"12","category":"Clothing","isbn":null}]}
```

And what I want to do is in place of where it shows the file path to the image I want to change that to the actual image for each object in the json string. Eventually I want to encode each image to base64 but I know how to do that part. I just need help changing `/var/www/pictures/photo-7h1sIsXQ.jpg` in this case to something I can work with and encode.

Comment: Seems like it would be simplest to check for it during your first iteration through the data.   If the row key eq image then run your regex on the value.  Maybe return everything after the last / if all your image paths are formatted as such

Comment: What's the question/problem? Don't you know how to open a file and read it?

Comment: @daxim I do but I dont know how to access it in $jsonData. How would I make a loop to access the image ref for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As daxim correctly said, you want to substitute the image data before you encode the data structure as JSON. You will want to use [MIME::Base64](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME%3a%3aBase64) for the encoding. The result will likely look similar to:

```
use MIME::Base64 qw(encode_base64);
use File::Slurp;

my $base64_encoded_image =  encode_base64 scalar read_file($filename, binmode => ':raw');
```

Comment: how do I change my json in this from what image is now to my new encoded string for each object I have?

Comment: @BluGeni ??? Just update that field in the data structure: `$row->{image} = $encoded`. Is this really that complicated?

Comment: sorry I didnt know you could do that, works perfectly though, thank you for the extra help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$row->{image}` before encoding.

Comment: perfect this is what I wanted, I have updated my code, my last issue is how do I change the json of image to my $document?